# Stalker Middleware Cannot Install Phing

Tags: software-installation

**Ubuntu Server 12.04**
-----------------------

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phing.info
Channel "pear.phing.info" is already initialized

sudo pear install phing/phing

WARNING: "pear/PEAR_PackageFileManager" is deprecated in favor of "pear/PEAR_PackageFileManager2"
Unknow remote channel: pear.pdepend.org
Unknow remote channel: pear.phpmd.org
Unknow remote channel: pear.phpdoc.org
Did not download optional dependencies: phing/phingdocs, pear/VersionControl_SVN, pear/VersionControl_Git, phpunit/PHPUnit, phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage, pecl/Xdebug, pear/PEAR_PackageFileManager, pear/Services_Amazon_S3, pear/HTTP_Request2, pdepend/PHP_Depend, phpmd/PHP_PMD, phpunit/phpcpd, phpunit/phploc, phpdoc/phpDocumentor, pear/PHP_CodeSniffer, pear/Net_Growl, use --alldeps to download automatically
phing/phing can optionally use package "phing/phingdocs" (version >= 2.10.1)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/VersionControl_SVN" (version >= 0.4.0)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/VersionControl_Git" (version >= 0.4.3)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pecl/Xdebug" (version >= 2.0.5)
phing/phing requires package "pear/Archive_Tar" (version >= 1.3.8), installed version is 1.3.7
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/PEAR_PackageFileManager" (version >= 1.5.2)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/Services_Amazon_S3" (version >= 0.3.1)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/HTTP_Request2" (version >= 2.1.1)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pdepend/PHP_Depend" (version >= 0.10.0)
phing/phing can optionally use package "phpmd/PHP_PMD" (version >= 1.1.0)<br>
phing/phing can optionally use package "phpdoc/phpDocumentor" (version >= 2.0.0b7)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/PHP_CodeSniffer" (version >= 1.5.0)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/Net_Growl" (version >= 2.6.0)
No valid packages found
install failed
```

I've  tried this command:

```
sudo pear clear-cache
```

but same problem

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install -y -u apache2 nginx memcached mysql-server php5 php5-mysql php-pear nodejs upstart
pear channel-discover pear.phing.info
pear install phing/phing
```

Solved :)

Answer (score 1):

run

```
pear upgrade-all
```

then install. success!

reference: http://blog.csdn.net/u014558668/article/details/79085497